# Dynamically Create and Destroy PictureBoxes

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, picturebox

I am trying to make a simple tile-based turn based strategy-game.

So I made a test-map with different things like trees, rivers etc.

My next step is to make classes that I call Unit, that holds the X-Y position and other data. Since Unit will be created/destroyed dynamically during the game (in a List>), I also want PictureBox containing the Unit tile-icon to be created/destroyed as needed.

I want to be able to click on a PictureBox, the box will make a mouse event, the event will check which class is connected to the PictureBoxand perform action as needed.

Dynamically Create and Destroy PictureBox in C#? Or should I make a grid of PictureBox?

Comment: Could you show with a picture what you want to achive or be more precise in your text? A PictureBox is nothing else than a class so creating one is as easy as instantiating any other class (e.g. var pb = new PictureBox()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go a different route.  Create one single PictureBox and draw everything in it's Paint event.  Do a nested loop through your map's x and y coords for the visible tiles and draw out those tiles using Graphics.Draw commands.  After you paint the background tiles you can loop though the unit list and paint those right on top.  You can do a simple hit-test on mouse down to see what is being clicked on.

This will be less resource intensive and also allow you to do better animations and graphics later (think sprites crossing tile boundaries or tiles larger than a single physical tile).

Comment: I like that solution, I will try to make something out of it.

Comment: Just a note in case you haven't done this before.  When you want to update the picture box's image with this method, call `PictureBox.Invalidate()` on it.  That will cause it to queue up a a redraw event and repaint it's self.